# How to set up custom PayPal payments on a web application

Tags: paypal

I am currently working on a project that needs to include some functionality to allow me to set an amount and a recipient for a PayPal payment, and then display a button to a user who can then complete the payment. I will also need to confirm that the payment was successful.

I am building it as an MVC application using the ASP.net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to be able to confirm the payment is successful, you need a server-side integration. Here is a demo pattern of the UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Note that it does fetch() XHR calls to two server endpoint of yours, which will need to implement v2/orders API calls to initially set up the payment, and then later capture it --- which provides confirmation of success/failure. More information on the server-side portion can be found here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ ; there is a .NET v2 Checkout SDK available.

Normally you need the ClientID and Secret of each receiver's REST APP (this is preferred, since PayPal account emails can change) -- but alternatively, you can use your own REST APP and specify the receiver's PayPal email address in the `payee` field:

```
                    purchase_units: [{
                        payee: {
                            email_address: 'replacewithrealemail@somewhere.com'
                        },
                        amount: {
                            value: '1.00'
                        }
                    }]
```